# Does a new answer on a migrated question cause an inbox notification?

Tags: support, notifications, migrated-questions

I just answered a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115300/euclidean-models) on Computer Science SE that had been migrated from Theoretical Computer Science SE. The asker only has an account activated on the latter site, and not on the site the question has been migrated to. I answered after the migration had occurred.

Will this person get a notification that I wrote a new answer?

If not, perhaps this should be a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't; there's no account to send a notification to.

But they *will* have gotten a notification that their question has been migrated. Hopefully they'll follow up on that, read the question and your new answer.

Comment: Hmmm, feared as much. Let's hope they will...